# How can an index in MongoDB render a query slower?

Tags: php, mongodb

** 
UPDATE
**

I posted an answer as it's been confirmed to be an issue

** 
ORIGINAL 
**

First, I apologize -- I have just started using MongoDB yesterday, and I am still pretty new at this. I have a pretty simple query, and using PHP my findings are this:

Mongo version is 2.0.4, running on CentOS 6.2 (Final) x64

```
$start = microtime(true);
$totalactive = $db->people->count(array('items'=> array('$gt' => 1)));
$end = microtime(true);
printf("Query lasted %.2f seconds\n", $end - $start);
```

Without index, it returns:

```
Query lasted 0.15 seconds
```

I have 280,000 records in people the database. So I thought adding an index on "items" should be helpful, because I query this data a lot. But to my disbelief, after adding the index I get this:

```
Query lasted 0.25 seconds
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Instead of count i used find to get the explain and this is the output:

```
> db.people.find({ 'items' : { '$gte' : 1 } }).explain();
{
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor items_1",
"nscanned" : 206396,
"nscannedObjects" : 206396,
"n" : 206396,
"millis" : 269,
"nYields" : 0,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"isMultiKey" : false,
"indexOnly" : false,
"indexBounds" : {
    "items" : [
        [
            1,
            1.7976931348623157e+308
        ]
    ]
}
}
```

If I change my query to be "$ne" 0, it takes 10ms more!

Here are the collection stats:

```
> db.people.stats()
{
"ns" : "stats.people",
"count" : 281207,
"size" : 23621416,
"avgObjSize" : 84.00009957077881,
"storageSize" : 33333248,
"numExtents" : 8,
"nindexes" : 2,
"lastExtentSize" : 12083200,
"paddingFactor" : 1,
"flags" : 0,
"totalIndexSize" : 21412944,
"indexSizes" : {
    "_id_" : 14324352,
    "items_1" : 7088592
},
"ok" : 1
}
```

I have 1GB of ram free, so I believe the index fits in memory.

Here's the people index, as requested:

```
> db.people.getIndexes()
[
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "stats.people",
    "name" : "_id_"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "items" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "stats.people",
    "name" : "items_1"
}
]
```

Comment: This is really interesting. Try using the linux `time` command to time multiple iterations.

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: It seems that "count" is currently not as clever as it could be: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1752

Comment: Can you please also give us the output of `db.people.getIndexes()`?

Comment: @NicholasTolleyCottrell added the index.

Comment: The index looks good to me. Maybe try reIndex()? http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-ReIndex

Comment: @NicholasTolleyCottrell - I have rebuilt the database twice from scratch and get the same results. I even tried a repairDatabase(), etc, no difference

Comment: I posted this on the mongo mailing list, we'll see if I get some answers there. I am starting to feeling this is a bug. https://groups.google.com/d/topic/mongodb-user/ih2-jyzWADc/discussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was confirmed to be a bug or something that needed optimization in the MongoDB engine. I posted this in the mongo mailing list and the response I received from Eliot Horowitz

> That's definitely a bug, or at least a path that could be way better
>   optimized.  Made a case: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5607

```
Priority:  Major
Fix Version/s: 2.3 desired
Type:  Bug
```

Thanks for those who helped confirming this was a bug =)

Answer (score 1):

Having an index can be beneficial for two reasons:

1. when accessing only a small part of the collection (because of a restrictive filter that can be satisfied by the index). Rule of thumb is less than 10%.
2. when the collection does not need to be accessed at all (because all necessary data is in the index, both for the filtering, and for the result set). This will be indicated by "indexOnly = true".

For the "find" query, both of this is not true: You are accessing almost the whole collection (206396 out of 281207) and need all fields data. So you will go through the index first, and then through almost the whole collection anyway, defeating the purpose of the index. Just reading the whole collection would have been faster.

I would have expected the "count" query to perform better (because that can be satisfied by just going through the index). Can you get an explain for that, too?

Comment: You cannot do an explain on count

Comment: There must be a way... I'll ask about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134716/how-to-get-an-explain-for-a-mongodb-count

Comment: I do like your explanation, but in this case only the index should be used (for a count) -- I tried to do a find specifying only "items" as the return field and it still shows indexOnly as false.

Comment: @ruinernix: Yes, count should be using the index. Did you return only items, or also the _id ?

Comment: If I use a find specify to not return _id and and only return items, the explain does show using the index only but it is still slower than using the count.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexing+Advice+and+FAQ#IndexingAdviceandFAQ-5.MongoDB%27s%24neor%24ninoperator%27saren%27tefficientwithindexes.

Which made me consider this solution. How about this?

```
$totalactive = $db->people->count() - $db->people->count(array('items'=> array('$eq' => 1)));
```

Comment: This is definitely faster. I'm getting 0.09ms instead of the 0.25ms/0.35ms for the same result.

Comment: Count($gt: 1) should be usually be faster than Count() if you have this index, though. Do you have a lot of data skew in this index (i.e. most data 0 or 1)?

Comment: If you mean the docs you linked to, they talk about $nin and $ne, not $gt (which does not have this problem).

Comment: Perhaps this is a question for 10gen. I just attended a tech talk hosted by one of their NYC devs, I'll shoot him an email.

Comment: I'm actually using : $db->people->count(array('items'=> 0)) vs what was posted above and that's how i got the faster response. Counting up to 280000 in php takes 0.03 seconds -- I still believe I should be expecting faster response considering it is indexed, but it's a step in the right direction.

Comment: btw the numbers I quoted in my first response are in seconds, not ms. With the non-indexed and using this solution instead I get 0.15 seconds. I thought I should add this tidbit because it makes a big difference, I'd be quite happy with 0.09ms :D

Comment: @Thilo I missed your question above, items is an item count, it can range from 0 to 1000 -- I optimized a little bit and removed the attribute if it's 0 and now i'm counting the nulls and that seems to be a lot faster but i'm still questioning the index issue above. I am down to 0.06s to calculate the number of people with items. From 0.15 to 0.06 is decent, but I'd like the count() performance since it's indexed!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide an example of an object in this collection? The "items" field is an array? If so, I would recommend you add a new field "itemCount" and put an index on that. Doing $gt on this field will be extremely fast.

Comment: Items is a number and the collection is very small. it is something like: { "slots" : 50, "last_update" : 1334325643, "_id" : "128713871987491", "items" : 0 }

Answer (score 0):

This is because your queries are near-full collection scans. The query optimizer is picking to use the index, when it should not use it for optimum performance. It's counterintuitive, yes, but it's because the cursor is walking the index b-tree and fetching the documents that the tree points to, which is slower than just walking the collection if it has to scan the almost the whole tree.

If you really need to do this kind of query, and you want to use that index for other things, like sorting, you can use `.hint({$natural: 1})`, to tell the query to not use the index.

Coincidentally, I posted about a similar issue in a blog post recently: http://wes.skeweredrook.com/testing-with-mongodb-part-1/

Comment: I posted my findings on the mongo mailing list, and Eliot (CTO of 10gen) responded that it is indeed a bug and or something that needs optimizations. It's been added as a major issue: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5607 -- i am going to close this one.