# How to get an explain for a MongoDB count?

Tags: mongodb

In MongoDB, you can get an explanation for how a query was executed, with interesting performance information:

```
> db.people.find({ 'items' : { '$gte' : 1 } }).explain()
```

Can I get the same for a "count" (which is not a query, but a command)?

```
> db.people.count({ 'items' : { '$gte' : 1 } })
```

Answer (score 26):

Mongo 3.0 introduced a new way of explaining non-cursor requests:

```
db.my_collection.explain().count()
```

See: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/#db.collection.explain

Comment: Note that you can also pass a query to count, i.e. `db.my_collection.explain().count({ 'items' : { '$gte' : 1 } })`

Answer (score 11):

Based on https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14098, a new future version will support this in the format:

```
db.runCommand({
    explain: {
        count: 'collectionName',
        query: {
            foo: 'bar'
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure that count(query) is short for find(query).count()--in other words, the explain is exactly the same. There's no specific *counting optimization* done, except maybe for a full collection count. For example, running a count on a non-indexed field for a range takes exactly the same amount of time as running a find.explain with the same range.

I wrote a function called timeCount that takes the average of the count function time, and then shows the explain output for comparison.

```
function timeCount(coll, query) {
  var n = 5;
  var total = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var start = new Date();
    db[coll].find(query).count();
    var end = new Date();
    total += (end - start);
    print("time[" + i + "]: " + (end - start) + "ms");
  }
  print("average time: " + (total / n));

  var explain = db[coll].find(query).explain();
  print("explain (from find): ");
  for(e in explain) {
    if(typeof explain[e] == "string" || typeof explain[e] == "number") {
      print(e + ": " + explain[e]);
    }
  }
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
> timeCount('test',{x:{$gt:5000}});
time[0]: 1339ms
time[1]: 1280ms
time[2]: 1347ms
time[3]: 1322ms
time[4]: 1299ms
average time: 1317.4
explain (from find): 
cursor: BtreeCursor x_1_y_1
nscanned: 995062
nscannedObjects: 995062
n: 995062
millis: 1390
nYields: 0
nChunkSkips: 0
```

Comment: "I'm pretty sure that count(query) is short for find(query).count()--in other words, the explain is exactly the same.". Yes, but you cannot easily get an explain for either: `db.people.find({}).count().explain()` is an error, just like `db.people.count({}).explain()`.

Comment: I was just saying that the explain from find() is going to give you the same results as a hypothetical explain from count.

Comment: No, that makes no sense. A find has to retrieve documents, a count does not. With an index, it should make a big difference.

Comment: My query above is using an index, and count takes the same time as find.explain. The mongodb team is still working on improving count so that it doesn't have to inspect each document, but it looks like it still does. Maybe 2.3 will be much better.
See here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1752

Comment: My point exactly. To check on this kind of progress one would like to see "explain".

Comment: @Thilo Wes is correct. An explain on a find() takes as long and executes the same query path as the find().count(). There is a difference in performance when you start returning documents but explain() doesn't do that. The reason count() is slow is because in MongoDB their indexes are not *counted* b-trees which store the amount of elements per node. If they'd use those (at the cost of 8 bytes per index entry mind you) you can calculate counts much faster than it does now. Now it has to do a b-tree walk and simply count all matching cases. That can take a bit of time.

Comment: @RemonvanVliet: So the result of an explain does not include the cost of actually returning any documents? How do you arrive at the `n` then, because you cannot know that before looking at the non-indexed fields in the document? Or were you only talking about the case where there is no query?

Comment: "Now it has to do a b-tree walk and simply count all matching cases. That can take a bit of time". Sure, but that should still be faster than a collection scan. And it should say "indexOnly:true" in the explain result. These are two things that I want to verify.

Comment: @Thilo Exactly, it includes the time to find them (so, scan for them, hence nscanned) just like a count() does but it doesn't actually create a cursor and return a batch. Hardly relevant since actually returning the documents is generally not the most time consuming thing but that's how it works. I agree that count().explain() becomes different/relevant the second they optimize count() cases though. Right now only a full collection count() is optimized (and in the case of sharded databases can produce an inconsistent result).

Comment: The explain on a count is indeed different from the explain on a find.  You can compare the explain() between the two using the syntax in marmor's answer to see the difference.  An efficient count will indicate "stage" : "COUNT", whereas a find will indicate "stage" : "FETCH".  An efficient count should not need to fetch any data, and instead purely use an index.  See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count which provides examples of situations where a count must FETCH.